# Not able to get constant response

Tags: java, jsf, richfaces

I am working on JSF and rich faces calendar.

```
<rich:panel header="Richfaces Calendar" style="width:600px">    
 <rich:calendar  value="#{CalenderBean.selectedDate}" id="calendar" datePattern=
 "d/M/yy HH:mm" cellWidth="50px" cellHeight="50px" disabled="false" 
 buttonLabel="Open Calendar" popup="true"   >           
 <a4j:support event="onchanged" reRender="changeDate"/>     
 </rich:calendar>

 <h:panelGroup id="changeDate">
 <h:outputText value="#{CalenderBean.selectedDate}" />
 </h:panelGroup>
</rich:panel>
```

In my managed bean class i am using String as a argument in setting method:

```
 public void setSelectedDate(String selectedDate) {  
    System.out.println("Date is going to set:"+selectedDate+".");
    this.selectedDate = selectedDate;  
}
```

Its work file when initially running it But when i open my.xhtml page once again then i am getting following error

```
'Wed Dec 07 12:00:00 PST 2011' could not be understood as a date.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because it is trying to restore the value from String to date on calendar component and which it is unable to do by it self so you need to use `java.util.Date` field in the bean to bind with

Comment: then i am getting `javax.servlet.ServletException: Error performing conversion of value ' of type class java.lang.String to type class java.util.Date for managed bean CalenderBean. ` this error
 `

Comment: You need to update setters/getters for `Date` also see [this example](http://www.mastertheboss.com/web-interfaces/271-richfaces-calendar-example.html) and compare your code

Comment: hi Jigar ,thanks i got the solution , i had used session as managed-bean-scope so i am getting this error, if i use request then its working fine.

Comment: It shouldn't be an issue for session scoped too if you'd used `Date`

Comment: @ Jigar Joshi : if i use Date then its showing `javax.servlet.ServletException: Error performing conversion of value ' of type class java.lang.String to type class java.util.Date for managed bean CalenderBean` error.

Comment: if i use Date then its showing `javax.servlet.ServletException: Error performing conversion of value ' of type class java.lang.String to type class java.util.Date for managed bean CalenderBean` error.

Comment: It shouldn't it is able to convert String to Date based on the datePattern

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5495/discussion-between-user1037552-and-jigar-joshi)